# Warning : attribute 'as' not declared in XSLT

Tags: arrays, json, xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the below code to store the elements in an array.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 
    <xsl:variable name="array" as="element()*">
        <Item>A</Item>
        <Item>B</Item>
        <Item>C</Item>
    </xsl:variable>
 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="$array"/>
    </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It threw a warning as **The 'as' attribute is not declared**.

I'm very new to XSLT. Can someone please help me out on this.

Also, does the variable `array` hold all three values A,B, and C?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is XSLT 2.0, you don't say which tool gives that warning but it is probably a tool checking against the XSLT 1.0 syntax (where `as` doesn't exist).

If you run the code with an XSLT 2 or 3 processor then the result of `<xsl:value-of select="$array"/>` would be a space separated list of the items in the sequence `$array` (yes, the variable is a sequence of nodes, not an array of nodes; arrays only exist in XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 and XQuery 3.1).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please elaborate on the tool? I'm using Visual Studio 2019. Will VS19 check against XSLT 1.0? If so, what needs to be done in order to run it with XSLT 2.0 in VS19?

Comment: Microsoft never produced a public XSLT 2.0 implementation and in Visual Studio uses XslCompiledTransform, I think, to run XSLT 1.0, and checks the syntax using the XSD 1.0 schema for XSLT 1.0. So in that toolchain you only have XSLT 1.0 support. Depending on your programming platform (.NET?) there are third party solutions for XSLT 2 (or these days 3) like Saxon 9 or 10 or XmlPrime or, if Node.js is the platform, then Saxon-JS, for Python perhpas SaxonC.

Comment: Inside of VS, to have syntax checking for XSLT 2, you would need to use an XSD 1.0 schema for that XSLT language, like the one given in the XSLT 2.0 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#schema-for-xslt